# How to report on least values in each category in MS Access?

Tags: microsoft-access, sql

IN MS Access, I have a table with a few different parameters, like this:

| Element | Weight (g) | Smallest Dimension (cm) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Orange | 100 | 5 |
| Apple | 90 | 4 |
| Banana | 130 | 2 |
| Grape | 40 | 1 |

These are grouped into sets, like this:

| Box | Contents |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Grape |
| 2 | Orange, Apple, Banana |

I'd like to produce a report that provides for each "box" or set the minimum value for each parameter, and if possible, the element it corresponds to, like this:

| Box | Min Weight (g) | Element with Min Weight | Min Smallest Dimension (cm) | Element with Min Smallest Dimension |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 | Grape | 1 | Grape |
| 2 | 90 | Apple | 2 | Banana |

The tricky thing (for me anyway) is that the element with the smallest value in one category won't in general also have the smallest value in the other category. Is there a reasonable approach to making this work?

Comment: please post what you could achieve so far, so we can build on it.

Comment: What are the primary keys of these tables?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Access installed, here is the code in SQLite, you might need some minor modification.

First, create a query to bring all data together (`AllData`):

```
select Box, Element, weight, SmallestDim
from boxes left join products on boxes.Contents = products.Element;
```

And here is your main query:

```
select minWeightItem.Box, minWeightItem.minWeight, minWeightItem.Element, MinDimItem.minDim, minDimItem.Element
from 
    (select AllData.Box, minWeight, Alldata.Element 
        from (select Box, min(weight) minWeight from AllData group by Box) minWeight 
        join AllData on minWeight.Box = AllData.Box and minWeight.minWeight = AllData.weight) minWeightItem
    left join (select AllData.Box, minDim, Alldata.Element 
        from (select Box, min(SmallestDim) minDim from AllData group by Box) minDim 
        join AllData on minDim.Box = AllData.Box and minDim.minDim = AllData.SmallestDim) minDimItem on minWeightItem.Box = minDimItem.Box;
```